# Mezclar arreglos sin perder el orden

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy aprendiendo esto de los métodos de orden en arreglos; tengo esta consigna:

> Una función recibe 2 arrays como parámetros y debe generarse un nuevo array con los dos arrays mezclados sin que sus elementos pierdan el orden por ejemplo:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3,4],
arr2=['h','o','l','a']
newArray = [1,'h','2','o','3','l',4,'a']


function mezclarArreglos(arr1,arr2){
    newArray = arr1.concat(arr2)
    console.log(newArray)
}
mezclarArreglos([1,2,3,4],['h','o','l','a']) 
/ /[1,2,3,4,'h','o','l','a']
```

Estoy atorado aquí, agradezco cualquier ayuda. Este codigo lo testee con los ejemplos y si da solo uno no. estoy tratando de entenderlo para escribirlo de modo que yo lo entienda.

```
intercalarDosArrays = (a1, a2) => {
let [l, s] = a2.length > a1.length ? [a1, a2] : [a1, a2];
return Array.from({ length: l.length * 2 }).map((_, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? l[i / 2] : s[Math.ceil(i / 2) - 1]).filter(el => el);
```

};

let result1 =intercalarDosArrays([1,2,3,4],['h','o','l','a']);
result1 //  [1, “h”, 2,”o”, 3,”l”,4,”a”]

let result2 =intercalarDosArrays([1,2,3,4],['h','p']);
result2 //  [1, “h”, 2, “p”, 3 , 4]

let result3 =intercalarDosArrays(['h','p'],[1,2,3,4]);
result3 //  [“h”, 1, “p”, 2, 3 , 4]

el tercero solo devuelve ['h',1,'p',2]...

Comment: Si los arreglos tuvieran diferentes tamannos, cual se supone seria el resultado, ej arr1 = 'hola' arr2 = '12'

Comment: cuando el primero es mas chico, el segundo solo devuelve el mismo numero de elementos...

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que si los concatenas, sencillamente pone un array luego del otro, para mezclar una letra y un número, siempre que se length sea igual podrías hacer algo así:

```
function mezclarArreglos(arr1,arr2){
    let newArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(arr1[i],arr2[i])
    }
    return newArray
   }

   mezclarArreglos([1,2,3,4],["a","b","c","d"]) // Devuelve [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']
```

Lo que hace es agrega a newArray el valor de arr1 con el índice I y el valor de arr2 con el mismo índice, y va corriendo el índice, entonces agrega, primera caracter de arr1 y primer caracter de arr2, luego segundo y segundo y así consecutivamente. Finalmente al terminar el for retorna newArray.

---

En caso de que el largo de los array pueda o no ser diferente, podrías hacer algo así:

```
function mezclarArreglos(arr1, arr2) {
  //Definimos variable donde guardaremos el largo del array más largo  
  let mostLargeArray = 0;
  //Chequeamos cual es el más largo y depositamos su length en mostLargeArray
  if (arr1.length >= arr2.length) {
    mostLargeArray = arr1.length;
  } else {
    mostLargeArray = arr2.length;
  }

  //Definimos variable que depositará los valores para retornar al final
  const newArray = [];

  //Generamos con el for la cantidad de iteraciones en base array más largo.
  for (let i = 0; i < mostLargeArray; i++) {
  
    //Verificamos si arr1 o arr2 tiene valor y solo si tiene valor lo agregamos a newArray    
    if (arr1[i]) {
      newArray.push(arr1[i]);
    }
    if (arr2[i]) {
      newArray.push(arr2[i]);
    }
  }
  //Retornamos newArray completo
  return newArray;
}

mezclarArreglos([1, 2, 3, 4], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]); // [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']

mezclarArreglos([1, 2, 3, 4,5,6], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]); //[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 6]

mezclarArreglos([1, 2, 3, 4], ["a", "b", "c", "d","e","f"]);//[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

---

Si cuando un array es más corto el se debe traer del otro solo la misma cantidad de caracteres, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
function mezclarArreglos(arr1, arr2) {
  //Definimos variable donde guardaremos el largo del array más corto
  let mostShortArray = 0;
  //Chequeamos cual es el más corto y depositamos su length en mostShortArray
  if (arr1.length <= arr2.length) {
    mostShortArray = arr1.length;
  } else {
    mostShortArray = arr2.length;
  }

  //Definimos variable que depositará los valores para retornar al final
  const newArray = [];

  //Generamos con el for la cantidad de iteraciones en base array más corto.
  for (let i = 0; i < mostShortArray; i++) {

  //Agregamos el valor de arr1 y de arr2 con el indice "i"
      newArray.push(arr1[i],arr2[i]);
  }
  //Retornamos newArray completo
  return newArray;
}

mezclarArreglos([1, 2, 3, 4], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]); //[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']

mezclarArreglos([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ["a", "b", "c", "d"]); //[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']

mezclarArreglos([1, 2, 3, 4], ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]); //[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']
```

Dejé todo comentado para que se entienda como funciona, espero ayude, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Buena respuesta..., ¡me ganaste! ;-)

Comment: Siempre es bueno poder dar una mano!

Comment: pasa que cuando los arrays no son del mismo tamaño, pone undefined o no los muestra, segun si array1 es mas grande que arra2. estoy leyendo este codigo que es   mas completo hojala pueda entenderlo.

Comment: Agregué a la respuesta al final una forma de hacerlo sin importar si el tamaño de los array es igual o diferente. Dejé todo comentado para que te sea mas sencillo entender el paso a paso.

Comment: Agregué también a la respuesta que si hay un array más corto solo se traigan del otro la misma cantidad de elementos. Favor si la solución te pareció adecuada para evacuar tu duda, darle al visto al costado de la respuesta para que no quede pendiente por siempre, ayuda a mejorar la reputación y le sirve a otros usuarios para saber que la respuesta es correcta y poder aplicar o aprovechar en otros proyectos. Gracias.

Comment: muchas gracias me quedo mas claro, explicas muy claro... gracias nuevamente¡

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti, me alegra haber contribuido. Quedo a las órdenes. No olvides por favor darle al visto al costado de la respuesta para que la pregunta no quede pendiente para siempre, ayuda a mejorar reputación y sirve a otros para saber que funciona y poder aplicarlo.